# sort by string length in Mongodb/pymongo

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mapreduce, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I was wondering if anyone knows how to sort a mongodb `find()` result by string length.

I have tried something like `db.foo.find().sort({item.lenght:-1})` but obviously doesn't work. Can somebody help me and also suggest me a way to do the same thing but in pymongo?

Comment: AFAIK mongodb does not support operations on String length. For eg you cannot have query where string length is less than or greater than something. I usually end up writing a js script for this task.

Comment: How about aggregate function?

Comment: @Dikesh I really do wish that was a possibility, but at present it is not. See the answer.

Answer (score 7):

There are lot of things ( and basic API ) I would personally **love** to see in the aggregation framework such as:

### Math functions

- log (as in logarithm)
- ceil
- floor

### Array

- sum

### String

- length

Just to name a few.

And that is without resorting to obscure usages of the **`$mod`** operator or other means in such cases as "ceil" and "floor". But I digress.

Your "string length" falls into this category. Raise a JIRA issue about it. But for now you you can use [mapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/) and the existing JavaScript functionality:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        emit( this.item.length, this.item );
    },
    function(key,values) {
        return values;
    },
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

So while that does actually have the "mapReduce" funky style of returning a re-shaped document and with of course everything matching the same length in an array, what it does do is take advantage of the nature of "mapReduce" ( not just restricted to MongoDB ) and allows the emitted "key" value to be sorted in the response.

Answer (score 6):

There is now a solution for this in MongoDB v3.4+ using the aggregation framework using [$strLenBytes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenBytes/). Given the following document:

```
{_id: 0, name: "Bob"}
```

We can use

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([{
    $project: {
         byteLength: {$strLenBytes: "$name"}
    }
}])
```

Which will return 3 for the number of bytes.

Comment: Actually that should be `[{ "$addFields": { "len": { "$strLenBytes": "$name" } }},{ "$sort": { "len": 1 }},{ "$project": { "len": 0 }}]` To fully replicate the action as requested by the OP, which is returning the documents "as is" but sorted. Kudos for mention though.

Comment: @NeilLunn Yeah I just concentrated on returning the length rather than the sorting as I felt the sorting was pretty straight forward, feel free to change the answer to cover both.

Answer (score 1):

No, actually is not possible.
I was dealing with a similar problem, what I did was to store the string length of every object as a property of the object itself. This bypassed the problem.

If you think that shall be implemented (I do) I recomend you to upvote the issue in JIRA, which, for some reason have not so many votes:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5319