# mongoexport export on specific string length?

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

In my job with have a mongoDB with 1 collection and 1 header - it is used to store a distinct 1-word dictionary for password hash cracking (as a part of penetration testing).

At this point our db is exported to a file that is approximately 500GB.
In an attempt to improve the process I want to export by string length, i.e, export only strings <= 6 char length.

I tried looking online and the best I found was another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22911656/sort-by-string-length-in-mongodb-pymongo) 
which says mongoDB doesn't support that, but it was 2 years ago so I hoped something might have changed.

If this is impossible I will have to split the file into small parts and use linux operation to do it - since mongo is so fast I was hoping to do it natively.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could try to specify a query with a regex like this

```
{ yourfield: { $regex: /^.{0,6}$/ } }
```

so your cmd line would look similar to this

```
mongoexport -h yourhost:31313 -d yourdb -c yourcoll -q '{ yourfield: { $regex: /^.{0,6}$/ } }'
```